# HTTP OPTIONS - Not Cacheable?

Tags: http, rest, hateoas

I'm designing a RESTful service aligning to HATEOAS principles as much as possible. As a result, I need a way to have my cool URLs return a list of links describing available options. I'm using HAL-JSON to facilitate the data format so that's all good, but I'm now considering what HTTP method should pull this.

I'm sure I could stick with a simple GET, but from reading over the HTTP RFC, it seems that OPTIONS might fit the bill here. My only concern is in bold:

> 9.2 OPTIONS
>
> The OPTIONS method represents a request for information about the
>   communication options available on the request/response chain
>   identified by the Request-URI. This method allows the client to
>   determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource,
>   or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or
>   initiating a resource retrieval.
>
> **Responses to this method are not cacheable.**

Could someone with more experience on the standards side of the web please explain why this is the case? In my view, you would certainly want clients caching this result at least for a short period of time, as in a fully HATEOAS system this call is likely to be made quite frequently to traverse the rel links to arrive at the operation you're looking for.

I'd also love some opinions on using OPTIONS vs a simple GET for retrieval of operations from a cool URL.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's not cacheable, period. Sorry.

Comment: Fair enough - but what I'm looking for is a reason for why this is the case.

Comment: History, more than anything; OPTIONS was defined that way to start with. The *underlying* reason is that HTTP caches are defined in terms of representations, which means the way you get something out of the cache is GET. This is why OPTIONS, PROPFIND, etc. caching are problematic.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that clarifies things nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The OPTION HTTP request returns the available methods which can be performed on a resource. (The objects methods)

I can not say for certain why you can not cache the response, but its most likely a precaution. Caching would have little value for the OPTION http method.

A Resource is "any information that can be given a name", that name is its URI. the response from the OPTIONs request is only a list of methods that can be requested on this resource (e.g. "GET PUT POST" maybe the response). To actually get at the information stored, you must use the GET method.

Comment: This all makes sense - I see what you mean about returning the verbs that can be used on this resource. I'm thinking about a system whereby you could do an OPTIONS on http://data/employees and retrieve a list of links with rels describing operations on that resource, whereas the GET on that same URI would actually retrieve a list of all employees in the system. Does that sort of setup make sense to you?

Comment: All links should be stored within the response of the GET, to allow the application to progress to another state. So your list of employees (an employee would have a URI), would be something like;

<employee href="/data/employee/123525">
<employee href="/data/employee/123423">

Comment: What you're saying seems to imply that a client of this API would have to retrieve all employees as the first action every time in order to see all operations performable. I'm looking for the discoverability of HATEOAS without the necessity of doing this first query. Or would it be better to simply define in my rel documentation the "employees" rel and all operations and use /data/employees/ as a cool URL?

Comment: a representation must be able to drive your clients state (application state), which is done with links. For your client to reach an employee resource, it must traverse these links. So yes, you would have to access the list first in order to know about the available employee resources.